# Haskell: generate and fill list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I have to make a game board in Haskell, by taking 2 ints a input, indicating the height and width of the board. The board has to be in the format `[[Int]]`, and all the spaces have to be filled with the integer `1`.

For example `makeBoard 2 3`, should return -> `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`

Comment: You may also consider having a board as a `Map (Int, Int) Int`; this would allow you to only store non-trivial ("non-empty", "non-wall") cells, and the code to update a cell value is already written for you.

Comment: So far I've managed to generate a single array with the correct amount of Ints, but drawing a blank about how to generate filled lists inside lists

Comment: @DaoDib: well why don't you show that attempt for a start?

Comment: 9000, it sounds like a good way to do it, but the tasks requires the specific format [[Int]]

Comment: @DaoDib: take your code that generates a list filled with `1`s and try to turn it into code that makes a list filled with an arbitrary given value. You'll be able to reuse that function to both fill a list with ints, and fill a list with other lists.

Comment: Willem, the only thing i got working is using the basics of basics:
makeBoard x = take x (repeat 1)

Comment: @DaoDib So how about `makeBoard x y = take y (repeat (take x (repeat 1)))`?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such

Comment: Alec, it's neccesary for a school project. I missed that I have to tag it as such. I appologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested [`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:replicate):

```
makeBoard :: Num a => Int -> Int -> [[a]]
makeBoard h w = replicate h $ replicate w 1
```

`replicate` takes thus an `Int` and an element `a` and generates a list `[a]` that contains *n* times that element. So the second `replicate` will return a list of ones, and the first replicate will replicate that list `h` times.

Note that `replicate n x` is actually equivalent to:

```
-- equivalent
replicate n x = take n $ repeat x
```

or shorter:

```
replicate n = take n . repeat
```